# Typescript error Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

I'm starting with React Native using Nativewind and I get this error.

> iOS Bundling failed 1748ms error: App.tsx:
> /Users/gcortinez/Projects/eynurse/eynurse-rn/eynurse_app/App.tsx: Use
> process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins

Anyone with the same error?..

I follow instructions from https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/expo using the template blank with typescript.

When I try to start expo I'm getting the error. I tried to create new project with JS same issue.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It could be due to the [pull request tailwindlabs/tailwindcss#11548: Make PostCSS plugin async to improve performance](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/11548) which was released in `v3.3.3` on July 13th. You could consider rolling back Tailwind CSS to `v3.3.2` until there is a more definitive resolution. Also, relevant issue: [marklawlor/nativewind#501](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/501).

Comment: Thanks, that solve the problem and has to be exactly as you say 3.3.2, i was using ^3.3.2 and gives me the same problem....

Comment: This did not work when I use it in a monorepo. It does work in its own repo but not in a monorepo.