# Development server returned response error code:500 in reactNative adding nativewind nativewind component library

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css, nativewind

[image]

Stuck in Error while Adding Tailwind CSS Library (Nativewind) to React Native App - Seeking Community Help

Hey fellow developers,

I hope you're all doing well! I'm currently facing a challenging issue while trying to integrate the Tailwind CSS library (Nativewind) into my React Native app. I've followed all the steps provided in the documentation, but unfortunately, I keep encountering an error whenever I restart the app.

Here's what I've tried so far to resolve the issue:

Deleted the "node_modules" folder and re-installed all dependencies.
Cleared the cache to ensure no stale data is causing the problem.
Modified the Babel config file to check for any misconfigurations.
Searched extensively on the internet and tried various methods suggested by the community, but none have worked so far.
Despite my efforts, the error persists, and I'm at a loss as to what to try next. I'm reaching out to this beautiful community to seek your expertise and suggestions on tackling this problem.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue with Nativewind or has successfully integrated Tailwind CSS into a React Native app, I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance. Any tips, code snippets, or possible solutions would be a huge help!

here is the doc link to which I referred: https://www.nativewind.dev/quick-starts/react-native-cli

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76690321/typescript-error-use-processcss-thencb-to-work-with-async-plugins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the [pull request tailwindlabs/tailwindcss#11548: Make PostCSS plugin async to improve performance](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/11548) which was released in `v3.3.3` on July 13th. You could consider rolling back Tailwind CSS to `v3.3.2` until there is a more definitive resolution. Also, relevant issue: [marklawlor/nativewind#501](https://github.com/marklawlor/nativewind/issues/501).

Comment: Hi I got the error again now I do change my tailwind version too

Comment: As the answer states, consider rolling back Tailwind CSS to `v3.3.2` until there is a more definitive resolution.